# foreach with where and condition parameter that must be checked by two variables

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm querying list of students passing controller 2 names using 2 variables Dname and Gname. In Dname some name that starts with D letter, in Gname som ename which starts with G letter.

```
innerJoinQuery.Where(item => 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Dname) || item.StudentName== Dname) 
    && 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Gname) || item.StudentName== Gname)
)
```

Condition is If I don't pass any names I get the whole list of students. 
**It works**

If I pass only Dname I get list of students with names starting with D. **It works**

If I pass only Gname I get list of students with names starting with G. **It works**

But if I pass both variables then I get nothing. But I want to get list of students with names starting on Dname var and Gname var. How can I accomplish this ?

**UPDATE**

If I use this code:

```
        (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Dname) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Gname ) 
    || item.StudentName.ToString() == Dname.ToString() ||
item.StudentName.ToString() == Gname.ToString())
```

and send only Dname, then I get exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Gname was null.
```

Comment: replace the && with || ?

Comment: Write up a name that starts with `G` __and__ starts with `D`

Comment: @bommelding Hmmmm gͩᵃᵛᶤᶰ

Comment: Can't you just write `item.StudentName == Dname || item.StudentName == Gname`? Is checking for `null` or whitespace really necessary? Think about it

Comment: @Rafalon If I write item.StudentName == Dname || item.StudentName == Gname then I always receive all names.

Comment: @bommelding what ???

Comment: @David, bommelding is just telling that a name can not both start with `G` **and** `D`

Comment: @Rafalon you are right. But I want to list names that start with G and with D only when I use this option. Otherwise , if I do not send any value I must get complete list with all names

Comment: It's a natural language thing: When you want the data in set A __and__ set B then you have to __or__ the conditions.

Comment: I think you want  use `contains` instead of `==`

Comment: @Justcode based on what "works" for OP, I'd say that `StudentName` only contains the first letter. But if it was not the case, I think he would prefer `StartsWith` over `Contains`

Comment: As he has written `starting with D` means there is a value after that.

Comment: StudentName contains full name, and in Dname I can send "David" , by this I want  to get only Davids from List. And with Gname option I can get Davids and let's say Georges. I mean all students with only such names.

Comment: The code as stated does not check "starts with", it will return students with the exact name specified. Can you clarify what you want done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not telling this is the way to go, but this would match your requirements:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Student
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class Program
{
    static List<Student> Students {get;set;}

    static void Main()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student{ Id = 1, Name = "G"},
            new Student{ Id = 2, Name = "D"},
            new Student{ Id = 3, Name = "G"},
            new Student{ Id = 4, Name = "G"},
            new Student{ Id = 5, Name = "D"},
            new Student{ Id = 6, Name = "E"},
            new Student{ Id = 7, Name = "F"},
            new Student{ Id = 8, Name = "G"},
            new Student{ Id = 9, Name = "H"}
        };

        WriteStudents(null, null); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
        WriteStudents(null, "D");  // 2,5
        WriteStudents("G", null);  // 1,3,4,8
        WriteStudents("G", "D");   // 1,2,3,4,5,8
    }

    static void WriteStudents(string GName, string DName)
    {
        var query = Students.Where(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GName)
                                     && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DName)
                                     || s.Name == GName || s.Name == DName)
                            .Select(s => s.Id); // used to print the Id

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", query));
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `WriteStudents` method could be written:

```
static void WriteStudents(string first = null, string second = null)
{
    var query = Students.Where(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first)
                                 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(second)
                                 || s.Name == first || s.Name == second)
                        .Select(s => s.Id); // used to print the Id

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", query));
}
```

So you could call it:

```
WriteStudents();         // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
WriteStudents("D");      // 2,5
WriteStudents("G");      // 1,3,4,8
WriteStudents("G", "D"); // 1,2,3,4,5,8
```

Comment: In this case when I send only one variable I get exception that other was null.

Comment: In *which* case?

Comment: when I send only Dname variable leaving Gname box empty

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the updated code and full exception message?

Comment: Well, then just remove those 4 `.ToString()`! Aren't they already strings anyway??